# I'm trying to set a default value of BigDecimal Column (quantiteCharge) in JPA Entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set a default value of `BigDecimal` column (quantiteCharge) in `JPA Entity`.

I have tried using annotation like this `columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'"` but it doesn't work:

**This is my entity:**

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail_tournee")
public class DetailTournee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer ID;


    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_CHARGE", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteCharge;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_CHARGES_SUPP", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteChargesSupp;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_DECHET", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteDechet;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_RETOUR", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteRetour;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_UNITE", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteUnite;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITE_VENDUE", columnDefinition="default '0.000000000'")
    private BigDecimal quantiteVendue;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define like this:

```java
@Column(name = "QUANTITE_CHARGE")
private BigDecimal quantiteCharge = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

It will look like this in the database:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a value to an attribute like this:

```
@Column(name = "QUANTITE_CHARGE")
private BigDecimal quantiteCharge = 0.00;
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work like that it shows an error

Comment: If you want to define like this, you need to do `private BigDecimal quantiteCharge = BigDecimal.ZERO;` for this to work.

Comment: @iswailyildiz yes it's fine with this answer you can write it in an answer and I will mark it as true if you want